# How to inActive Azure Pass subscription

Tags: azure

I have 6 months azure subscription by using azure pass , however I am not using azure to full extent . I want to use that subscription later , How do I InActive that subscription .

[image]

Currently it is Active , Need help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a subscription-related question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deactivate an azure pass subscription 
Once you activated your azure pass it will start the count down of your free trail period

If you have an MSDN account you can get 150$ every month for a month